# Is "none of" an antonym of "any of"?

Tags: pronouns

> If there is any (at least one) of a movie theater, a baseball stadium, and an amusement
>   park in that town, I would decide to live there.

I would like to reverse the meaning of this.  My example is as follows:

> If there is none of a movie theater, a baseball stadium, and an
>   amusement park in that town, I would decide to live there.

I have consulted a dictionary, but could not find the usage of "none of A, B, and C"

Comment: You're saying that you would live in the town if it had any of the following venues:  a movie theater, a baseball stadium, or an amusement park; but that if it has **none of them** you would not move there.  The phrase **none of them** requires that the list of places be antecedent.  If the list of places will follow, then you could say "I would not live in a town if it had **none of these** venues:  a movie theater, a baseball stadium, or an amusement park."

Comment: For both your examples it would be better to forget about trying to include ***any/none***. So for #1, *If there **is a** movie theater, baseball stadium, and amusement park in that town...* (don't keep repeating the articles; it's just awkward). For #2, *If there **isn't a** movie theater, baseball stadium, or amusement park in that town.*

Comment: Does "If there is a movie theater, baseball stadium, and amusement park in that town" means if at least one of them is in that town ?

Comment: @rama9: with **and**,  all must be present in order to satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say that those constructions are very clumsy and you would not normally express it that way.

> If there's a theater, baseball stadium or amusement park, I would live in that town.

'any of' is implied by the 'or'.

Conversely,

> If there isn't a theater, baseball stadium or amusement park, I would not live in that town.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight problem in that the first sentence isn't really natural. It would more commonly be expressed as

> If there were a movie theater, a baseball stadium, or an amusement park in that town, I would decide to live there.

Note the usage of the [subjunctive](http://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference) **were** to indicate a hypothetical condition.

To negate it, you simply say

> If there weren't a movie theater, a baseball stadium, or an amusement park in that town, I would decide not to live there.

If you really want to push the negative angle, you could say

> If there were neither a movie theater, nor a baseball stadium, nor an amusement park in that town, I would decide not to live there.

Comment: "If there weren't a movie theater, a baseball stadium, or an amusement park in that town, I would decide not to live there." - but what if there were no amusement part, but there was a movie theater? This is ambiguous. OP asks about having **none** of them.

Comment: @Davo, with **or**, any one of them would satisfy. with **and**, all must be present to satisfy.

Comment: Yes, quite so. But again, the OP asks for a sentence indicating **none** of these things.

Comment: @Davo, not one means none.

Comment: Great edit, thanks. Readers will have differing opinions on whether "or" is exclusive or not.